# In an array of strings, how can I print the first element x number of times, and then print the second element x number of times, and so on?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, foreach

For example:
myArray = ["Dave", "Tom", "Pete"];

I would like to print each element in myArray 3 times in the following format:

Dave
Dave
Dave
Tom
Tom
Tom
Pete
Pete
Pete

forEach loops (at least on their own) don't seem to handle what I'm trying to do. I'm going back and forth between different array and string methods but I feel there's a combination I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: use a nested for loop plz

Comment: This isn't a code writing or tutorial service. You are expected to show your own attempts to solve your issue yourself...or any research that you have done. Then people help you correct any specific  problems  in ***your code***

Comment: Think about a function or two you could write to do this. (Then try it and post your attempt)

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do here is have two nested for loops. The first one looping through your array of strings; the second loop contains whatever mechanism you want to use for "printing" your strings. I have two variables here, one being your array, and the second a simple *x* to choose how many times you want your string printed.

In addition, as the comment above said, this isn't a code writing service. Next time you really need to give an example of what you did that didn't work, and asked a question based on that. A forEach loop should actually work just fine as well.

```
let myArray = ["Dave", "Tom", "Pete"];
let x = 3;
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
        // whatever printing mechanism you would like goes here. let's make some html
        let element = document.createElement('p');
        element.textContent = myArray[i];
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do something "x times" for every element, that's exactly what you should do: "for every element": "do ... x times"

```js
["Dave", "Tom", "Pete"].forEach((e) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) console.log(e);
});
```